# Display Geojson data from PHP API (http://localhost/sample.php) on google map

Tags: google-maps, geojson, php

I have `PHP` API (http://localhost/api.php) that gives data in `GeoJSON` format, how can I show that `GeoJSON` data on Google map ?

Dragging & Dropping `GeoJSON` data on map is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Ajax`  and `leaflet` for displaying `GeoJSON` data.
[Here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) is a detailed example of GeoJSON in leaflet.

You have to modify 'Ajax' given below according to your php.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPHP.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
```

`var gj = L.geoJson(response, {
            style: oldStyle
        }).addTo(map);
     });`

Comment: How can I do it on google maps?